# Print a PHP script's echo in another PHP script without include

Tags: php

I have a file, let's call it `first.php`. It echoes a lot of text. Inside that text I also want to include something another file, `second.php` echoes. I'd like to do this without including the code from `second.php`, because there are collisions.

TL;DR I want a PHP script to execute another one, wait for it to print, and then echo whatever it printed.

Tried

```
echo something
include second script
echo something else
```

But it doesn't work because of said collisions. The second script only prints a short plain text.

Better example

- a.php prints "hello" and "world" and declares `$i=1`
- b.php prints "beautiful" and declares `$i=2`
- I want to print "hello beautiful world" and have `$i=1`

Comment: maybe that can help you : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-end-clean.php . Add `ob_start();` before your echo and `$var = ob_end_clean();` after. All your content will be into the variable $var.

Comment: @pbolduc How will that prevent the second script from reassigning the variable `$i`?

Comment: "I'd like to do this without including the code from second.php, because there are collisions." Fix the actual issue instead of trying to come up with a broken crap solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the second script through the CLI with `shell_exec`

```
echo something
shell_exec("php second.php");
echo something else
```

However, this won't work if the second script needs to access variables that are set by the webserver, like `$_GET` or `$_SERVER`. If you need to pass certain variables along, you can send them as command line arguments. But the second script will then have to access them using `$argv`, not `$_GET`.

```
shell_exec("php second.php " . escapeshellarg($_GET['id']));
```

`second.php` can get the ID from `$argv[1]`.

Comment: The script requires a GET variable, script.php?id=xx . Can't I just add that in the exec()? Also, is the full path not needed here?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can pass that along.

Answer (score 1):

Imo you should really solve the actual problem by not re-using variables which are sharing scope. If you cannot do that it means you are putting too much in the current scope. However if you really want to do it you could wrap it in a function (which has its own scope).

```
<?php

$i = 1;
echo 'hello';
echo call_user_func(function() {
    // in your case this would be a include statement

    $i = 2;

    return 'beautiful';
});
echo 'world';

var_dump($i); // 1
```

If you actually need to "import" variables from the current scope create a closure instead:

```
<?php

$i = 1;
echo 'hello';
echo call_user_func(function() use ($theVariable) {
    // in your case this would be a include statement

    $i = 2;

    return 'beautiful';
});
echo 'world';

var_dump($i); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include the second file in a function. Functions have their own variable scopes. So, variables of the second file can not overwrite variables with the same name of the first script file.

```
$myvar = 1;
include 'first.php';
callSecond ();
echo $myvar;

function callSecond () {
    include 'second.php';
}
```

**echo $myvar** would give **1**, even when 'second.php' assigns $myvar = 2;